# Java Abstraction: abstract class delegates abstractions vs. concrete class uses common abstractions

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Say i am implementing a simple interface like Animal. Broadly speaking, there are two ways to go about doing that:

1. implement the interface's method in the abstract class, and create  abstract methods for any implementation specific logic needed.
2. implement the interface method in the concrete classes, and move the common logic in the abstract class with protected access.

I'd like to understand if-

- there are any objective benefits of one way over the other in terms of design.
- is it recommended to stick with just one way in a single project (code maintainability/readability).

```
public interface Animal {
    void makeSound();
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseAnimal implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        //do something which is common for all implementaions
        doSomeImplementaionSpecificStuff();
    }

    public abstract void doSomeImplementaionSpecificStuff();
}

public class Dog extends BaseAnimal implements Animal {
    public void doSomeImplementationSpecificStuff(){
       //do something specific to a dog
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseAnimal implements Animal {
    public void doCommonStuff() {
        //any common logic that can be shared between concrete  implementation goes here
    }
}

public class Dog extends BaseAnimal implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
       doCommonStuff();
       //do something specific to a dog
    }
}
```

Comment: When i doubt, follow the example of the JDK itself: prefer #1.  #2 breaks the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @duffymo can you please elaborate how #2 breaks Liskov's?

Comment: The abstract class that fails to implement the interface can not satisfy IS-A: not an instance of the interface. You cannot use the abstract class in any context calling for the interface type.

Comment: yes, i agree. I apologize, but there was a typo when i posted this initially. I have corrected the classes appropriately now.

Comment: I wonder if this is needed anymore now that JDK 8 introduced default behavior into interfaces?  Abstract classes have been with us since JDK 1.  Time for a change in thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways are not always interchangeable.
Your first example sets a constraint for subclass that requires to implement a specific method that is a part of the `makeSound()` method.
Using that way couples strongly the implementation of the subclass to which one of the parent class.
Besides, the subclass may still subclass `makeSound()` as it is not `final`.
So I would use that way only for very specific scenarios :

- to define a factory method that subclass have to define because parent class relies on that (abstract factory)
- to define a general algorithm and let subclass to define some specific parts of that algorithm (template method).

In the general case you want to use the code of the second example but by doing `BaseAnimal` a `Animal` too :

```
public abstract class BaseAnimal implements Animal {
    public void doCommonStuff() {
        //any common logic that can be shared between concrete  implementation goes here
    }
}

public class Dog extends BaseAnimal implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
       doCommonStuff();
       //do something specific to a dog
    }
}
```

Note that in Java 8, default interfaces rely you from defining the abstract class that only defines common methods :

```
public interface Animal {
    void makeSound();
    default void doCommonStuff() {
            //any common logic that can be shared between concrete  implementation goes here    
}
```

Note also that exposing `doCommonStuff()` in the API of the abstract class is not necessarily fine. Is client should be able to call it ? 
If that is an implementation detail, you could extract it into a support class (`AnimalDelegate`) and favor composition over inheritance by composing an `AnimalDelegate` into the `Animal` subclasses.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that BaseAnimal should be an Animal too, I had missed it initially.
You also make a good point about exposing doCommonStuff() in the API. Creating an AnimalDelegate also seems agreeable if one doesn't have a strong use case for the template method pattern. In general, can't the template method pattern be replaced completely by providing a delegate? since the template method pattern will always be prone to exposing the 'variants' to the client?

Comment: You are welcome. Of course you may. But that will give more freedom to the subclasses. Is is desirable ? It may be as it may not.  In a general way to not expose variant part to clients (the template method here), the client should program by interface. And if exposing the variant part is a very problem, factories can help.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that you can put logic in the parent class, and create a sort of default method if you don't want to implement all the method of a parent/abstract class.
 The interface force you to implement all the methods no matter what.

```
public abstract class BaseAnimal {
    public void doCommonStuff() {
        System.out.println("doComon1");
    }
    public void doCommonStuff2() {
        System.out.println("doComon1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperDog superDog = new SuperDog();
        superDog.doCommonStuff();
    }
}
```

two implementation could be:

```
public class cat extends BaseAnimal {
    @Override
    public void doCommonStuff() {
        //specific logic
    }
    @Override
    public void doCommonStuff2() {
        //specific logic
    }
}

public class Dog extends BaseAnimal {
    @Override
    public void doCommonStuff() {
        //specific logic
    }
    // don't override the doCommonStuff2() method so you have the parent implementation
}
```

and also, with abstract classes you can make a mix:

```
public class SuperDog extends BaseAnimal {
    @Override
    public void doCommonStuff(){
        super.doCommonStuff();
        System.out.println("do specific after common stuff");
    }
}
```

The last one, can call the parent logic and also add a specific logic. With interfaces you cannot do any of those.

Comment: yes, it's a good case for the template method pattern, i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a default common way to implement the interface that most subclasses would use, then just implement the overriden method that way in the abstract class. Any subclass that needs it that way can just leave it as is. Any subclass that needs it a completely different way can override and reimplement it entirely. Any subclasses that wants to use the default implementation but then add some stuff to it can override and then call `super.makeSound()` as part of the implementation.

Don't forget to document exactly what the default implementation is.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the interface that your abstract class is providing to subclass implementors.

Document the methods that the subclass can use or override.  Make sure that the docs tell the subclass implementor what he needs to know to use your base class properly.

Now:

- Option 1: In almost all cases this turns out to be a bad idea, because your abstract class is assuming that subclasses will satisfy the `Animal` interface in a *particular way*, and will only need to change the bits you expect them to change.  Assumptions like that turn out to be wrong eventually.  If you document that `doSomeImplementaionSpecificStuff`, you'll usually find that all the clauses about when that method will be called and what it is expected to do will be embarrassing.  That said, *sometimes* an abstract class like this can be useful if it is *a* base class that an implementor *might* use, and not *the* base class that an implementor is *expected* to use.
- Option 2: This is OK, as long as `doCommonStuff` is "commonly used stuff" that a subclass implementor can choose to use or not, and not something that a subclass implementor *must* call, and certainly not something that the subclass implementor must call at a particular time.  If you can avoid having state in that abstract class, then you might want to move that common stuff into a utility library.

In all cases the thing to remember is this:  When your abstract base is used, it is the **subclass implementor** that is trying to implement the `Animal` interface.  He gets to make all the decisions about how exactly that is done.  Your base class is an offer to help with that in a specific way, which the subclass implementor can take or leave.